# Simple encryption of a UTF-8 string where the result is NULL terminated string?

Tags: c++, algorithm, encryption

I want to encrypt what I send to a client on a server (not necessarily going for safety, just to prevent someone from easily seeing the data on something like Wireshark).

I'm looking for an algorithm where the result is still a NULL terminated string but can be decrypted back into a utf-8 string quite quickly and easily. The networking library I'm using only lets me send NULL terminated strings to clients, that is why. I'm using a UDP library with reliable packets.

What are some algorithms that could do this sort of thing?

Thanks

Comment: May I ask how long are the messages going to be ?

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth Some could be around 3-4kb but on average, about 50 bytes

Comment: Message integrity is important ? (Do you want it to be temper-proof ?)

Comment: you could just escape 0s by some non-null char.

Comment: I do not want it to slow the server down, but at the same time, if a little more cpu usage can gain me a lot more security I would do that.

Comment: You're using a networking library that doesn't support arbitrary payloads? My advice would be to find another networking library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xor all bytes with some value (or another string).

Before sending data, replace all '\0' characters with 0xff 0xfe and all 0xff with 0xff 0xff. (you could use other values, obviously)

When receiving the data, reverse the process - replace 0xff 0xff with 0xff and oxff 0xfe with 0. then xor with key.

Alternatively you could base64-encode encrypted data to take care of `\0` characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scramble your data, you can look for functions that do *Base64* encoding, *ROT13*, or *HEX* encoding.

Comment: I still think XOR keys would be better than those three options.

Comment: That's right. XOR gives you a 1 to 1 ratio of byte lengths and is less readable than ROT13.

Answer (score 0):

**If** you need the ciphertext to be the same size as the cleartext, then you need character mappings from [1..255] to [1.255], so you can do something like

```
cipherbyte = ((clearbyte + keystreambyte) mod 255)+1
```

Are you sure you have a clear path for every character in [1..255]?

**If** you don't mind ciphertext larger than cleartext, then you can XOR (mod 256) and adopt escape mechanisms such as what SigTerm suggested.

**Note** that in either case, you need some keystream material and have to decide on some key management strategy.  Reading up on [stream ciphers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher) might give you a good start, just keep in mind that using the same key twice is equivalent to using the same encoding over and over again (not very strong).

Comment: Let's say without loss of generality that keystreambyte is always 0.  Now clear 1 => cipher 2, clear 2 => cipher 3, ... clear 254 => cipher 255, clear 255 => cipher 1.  Looks like a 1-to-1 mapping to me.